# DataTable Date sorting issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

Table have date like - `Apr 24 2018`. but it show the data in table as the sorted in the alphabetic order of the month in a specific year not the order of the date.

This order I got in table:

`Apr 24 2018,Jun 19 2012,Nov 28 2012,Oct 29 2012`

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Share more about your questions & share the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you have to sort by `yourDate.getTime()`

> The **getTime() method** returns the numeric value corresponding to the
>   time for the specified date according to universal time.

To learn more about `getTime()` take a look at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).